# double inheritance (Enums)

Tags: java, c#, inheritance, enums

Hey i'm having a problem with enums unlike java that you can perform two values or infinite values in enums , c# can hold 1 ( i think ) , for example :

```
public enum Beginner : int
```

this enum is inheriting from int only , can i make it inheriting from more than one ?

while java :

```
  public enum name 
{
   imAwesome(value,value);

   public name(int,short)
   {
   this.value = int;
   this.value1 = short;
   }
}
```

Comment: C# enums are little more than a grouping of named integers - it can only be of one integer type.

Answer (score 0):

Try to see the source code of the TimeUnit class. TimeUnit is a enum that encapsulates its own methods, including the enums, that have methods as well.

http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.java.html

Comment: The question asks about a c# solution, not a java solution.